# How to do sampling based on the some conditions in parallel Python?

Tags: python, random, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

Assume I would like to do sampling in parallel based on a condition.

For example, give the matrix `A`. I want to sample the `p` pairs of indices `(i,j)` such that `A[i][j] != 5`

```py
import numpy as np
import random

A = np.random.randint(10, size=(5000, 5000)) # assume this is fixed

p = 400  # sample 400 index

res = set()
cnt = 0

while cnt < p:
    r, c = random.randint(0, A.shape[0]-1), random.randint(0, A.shape[0]-1)
    if A[r, c] != 5 and (r,c) not in res:
        res.add((r,c))
        cnt += 1
```

Above is my attempt. However, the matrix `A` and the number of samples `p` can be very large. Can we do it in parallel? Like use `joblib`, `multiprocessing`? Or any fast way to obtain the `row` and `col`?

Comment: Did you try the following sample code?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/multithreading.html

Comment: Thanks, I do not how to modify above sample code since my sampling has some conditions.

Comment: If you need speed, vectorization and cache efficiency can be also important. Do you need even sampling in both indices? Can you systematically go through the indices? Sampling the matrix in random points is quite time-consuming. Doing `np.argwhere(A[i] != 5)` in a loop by increasing `i` is possibly one of the fastest solutions. This way you can get the first `p` non-5 values.

Comment: Comparing integers is fast compared to loading values from the memory, which can be hundreds or thousands of times slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Numba** to speed up this code. Numba can generate fast (parallel) functions at runtime using a just-in-time compiler (JIT). Using a smaller datatype like `np.int8` save some memory space and result in a faster execution time. Indeed, smaller arrays can be *read/written faster from/into RAM*. Moreover, they are more likely to *fit in the CPU cache* speeding up random access. While you can parallelize the random picking, this is quite hard and the creation of threads can be more expensive than the actual computation regarding the chosen parameters. Still, Numba can improve its speed by a large margin by just (mostly) removing the overhead of the Python interpreter.
Here is the resulting code:

```py
# Initial conditions

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import random

@nb.njit('int8[:,:](int_, int_)', parallel=True)
def genArray(n, m):
    res = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.int8)
    # Parallel loop
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        for j in range(m):
            res[i, j] = np.random.randint(10)
    return res

p = 400
A = genArray(5000, 5000)

# Actual computing code

@nb.njit('(int8[:,::1], int_)')
def genPosSet(A, p):
    maxi = A.shape[0]-1
    res = set()
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < p:
        r, c = random.randint(0, maxi), random.randint(0, maxi)
        if A[r, c] != 5 and (r,c) not in res:
            res.add((r,c))
            cnt += 1
    return res

res = genPosSet(A, p)
```

This implementation of `genPosSet` takes 64 us on my machine while the initial function takes 1350 us. The new implementation is thus **21 times faster**.

Note that the time to create/delete threads (1 thread/core) and share the work between them takes usually from 10 us to 1000 us.

Note that if `p` is not much smaller than `A.size * prob` where `prob` is the probability to find a value different of 5, then the current algorithm is not very efficient. In this case, it is better to filter the values that are different of 5 before picking random locations. If `p` is not much smaller than `A.size`, then the best solution is to shuffle all the possible locations that can be picked and finally extract the `p` first values of the resulting list.

Comment: This code parallelizes the matrix generation, but the matrix is considered to be a given matrix, and the speed gain is mostly achieved there. `genPosSet`, on the other hand, is not parallelized, however, numba does a good job with the loop on a single thread too.

Comment: @DanielTuzes What do you mean by "the matrix is considered to be a given matrix"?

Comment: In OP's code: `A = np.random.randint(10, size=(5000, 5000)) # assume this is fixed`

Comment: @DanielTuzes Thank you for pointing this. I have understood first that the dimension the array was fixed and not that the variable was already predefined. I updated the answer to focus on the random picking part.